# Add new element to Json array

Tags: php, arrays, json

**I got a Json Array**

```
{
  "cms18.test.silverbee.nl": {
    "domain": "cms18",
    "template": "default"
  },
  "dmmd.test.silverbee.nl": {
    "domain": "dmmd",
    "template": "default"
  },
  "opmaat.test.silverbee.nl": {
    "domain": "opmaat",
    "template": "opmaat"
  },
  "opmaatdebiteurenadvies.nl": {
    "domain": "opmaat",
    "template": "opmaat"
  },
  "navbar.test.silverbee.nl": {
    "domain": "navbar",
    "template": "default"
  },
  "test18.test.silverbee.nl": {
    "domain": "test18testsilverbeenl",
    "template": "test"
  },
  "huisartsplus.test.silverbee.nl": {
    "domain": "huisartsplustestsilverbeenl",
    "template": "huisartsplus"
  },
  "robertenrademaker.test.silverbee.nl": {
    "domain": "robertenrademakertestsilverbeenl",
    "template": "robert-en-rademaker"
  },
  "tilburg.test.silverbee.nl": {
    "domain": "tilburgtestsilverbeenl",
    "template": "default"
  },
  "cbk-groningen.test.silverbee.nl": {
    "domain": "cbk_groningentestsilverbeenl",
    "template": "cbk-groningen"
  },
  "getbusyinc.test.silverbee.nl": {
    "domain": "getbusyinctestsilverbeenl",
    "template": "getbusyinc"
  }
}
```

**And i got a Php script that gets input values to push a new element to Json array from above i dont know if this is oke but when i try to push it i get an 0 with the input values next to it.**

```
 <?php 
    $url = $_POST['new_url'];
    $t_d = $_POST['t_d'];
    $t_t = $_POST['t_t'];
    $str = $url.":{"."domain:".$t_d.","."template:".$t_t."},";
          if (isset($url)) 
          {
            array_push($list, $str);
          }
    ?>
```

Comment: It's not a json array, it is a hash. You shouldn't push into it - but set new key with appropriate value.

Comment: you don't add to json. you DECODE the json to a native structure, add your new stuff to that structure, then RE-encode to json. And what you have is not an array (`[...]`). you have an object (`{...}`).

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Q7Eqve1K

Comment: Sorry for that i just putted the inportant code in stackoverflow but in this link is the full code i already Decoded and at the end encoded and i get this at the end "0":{"testing url":":{domain:testing domain,template:testing template},"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's really a json array you should try decode the string into array:

```
<?php 
$decoded_list = json_decode($list, true); 
?>
```

then just push the new element into the array? 
Finally you can do

```
<?php 
$list = json_encode($decoded_list); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = $url.":{"."domain:".$t_d.","."template:".$t_t."},";
$str = json_decode($str);

          if (isset($url)) 
          {
            array_push($list, $str);
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, decode your json:

```
$list = json_decode($list, true);
```

Then, create an array from your user input values (basic example below):

```
$url = "google.com";
$t_d = "google";
$t_t = "googletwo";

$data[] = $url;
$data[] = array('domain' => $t_d, 'template' => $t_t);
```

Append the data:

```
if(isset($url)){
    array_push($temp, $data);
}
```

Finally, encode it back to json like so:

```
$json = json_encode($data);
```

output:

```
[
  "google.com",
  {
    "domain": "google",
    "template": "googletwo"
  }
]
```